# Is there a way to access Doctrine repositories from stand-alone code?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have a Symfony 4 app which is complete and working. Any uploaded files are put inside an upload folder outside the doc root and accessed via a separate cdn url.

Inside the upload folder I have a htaccess file that redirects any request, let’s say for example an image, to a php file which then serves the image.

What I want to be able to do is send an auth key along with the image request so that the standalone index.php file can check the user is valid from the database.

This means I need some way of accessing the symfony entity manager from outside of symfony, by including it. The other option would be a curl request to a symfony controller, but I’d rather not add additional network requests if possible. The third option is a separate pdo direct to the database and make sql queries... but again I’d prefer to use the symfony entity manager by including symfony somehow so I can use other features if needed.

I actually tried including the symfony bootstrap in the index.php but that then drags in the need for routing to work which isn’t needed in this case.

Comment: theoretically you only need the kernel (and boot it `$kernel->boot()`) and access its container (`$kernel->getContainer()`), and fetch that repository `$container->get(RepositoryClass::class)` haven't done it, so I might be wrong.

Comment: The symfony manager is not "symfony's", but Doctrine's.

Comment: [Here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/getting-started.html#obtaining-the-entitymanager) you can see how to instantiate the entity manager. But you'll probably find more trouble along the way trying to get all the dependencies wiring done. You'll be better served by letting Symfony do its work, if you are already using it. Unless you have a real, measurable performance problem, don't try to optimize for optimization's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access EntityManager like that:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

(new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');

$kernel = new Kernel('dev', true);
$kernel->boot();

$user = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')->getRepository(Repo::class)->find(id);


dd($user->getRoles());
```